# How can I fix the following error while using certificate on request?

Tags: python-requests, ssl-certificate, http-post

I am getting the following error while using certificate in requests to post data to a website.

It works fine when I set `verify = false`.

> Error:-
>   requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))

Comment: You should also include your code, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable it using the urllib module.

```
import requests
import urllib3
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

res = requests.get('https://example.com',verify=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
import requests

try:
  x = requests.get(url, verify=True)
except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
  x = requests.get(url, verify=False)

print(x)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/6045800)! Please translate to English. You can also see [the list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297734/6045800) of other non-English versions of Stack Overflow.